# Hi is there any disadvantages in using spring cloud function over python in gcp cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Hi I am new to the gcp cloud function. I am a mainly spring developer. In the gcp cloud function I see there are ways to write native python code. But since it has also support of spring cloud function gcp adaptor. I was wondering is there any disadvantages in using spring cloud function instead of Python in Google cloud function

Answer (score 1):

Your question will be closed because it's opinion based. But I provide mine because I was also a Java Spring developer and I changed of language before Cloud Functions come with Java.

Java have strengths and weaknesses:

- (+) Spring ecosystem is awesome
- (+) Java is well known by many developer
- (+) New framework like Quarkus or Micronaut are good alternative to Spring (quicker to start)
- (+) You have several flavor of Java (Kotlin, Groovy and Scala)
- (-) Spring is slow, very slow, too slow... It scans all your classes and it's awful with only one CPU or a part of CPU like with Cloud Functions (startup time: 20s for a simple hello world!)
- (-) Java love long long file for doing few!
- (-) Java likes memory, a little bit too much. And because you pay the used resource, Java is more expensive than other languages

Python, from my Java developer point of view, has strengths and weaknesses

- (+) Python is concise, no code for nothing
- (+) Python is easier to write and to read (indentation, no semi colon)
- (+) Python is dynamically typed
- (+) Python runs almost everywhere and everybody know it
- (-) Python is dynamically typed. It's awful when you come from Java and type safe environment. Auto-completion does not always work, it's possible to do unreadable things
- (-) Python start fast, but it's very slow for compute intensive stuff
- (-) Python is monothread
- (-) Python doesn't love Windows OS

So, it's only my opinion. My favorite playground today is Go:

- (+) Type safe
- (+) Very efficient (memory, runtime, cold start, container size,...)
- (+) Multi process (goroutine are awesome)
- (+) Easy to read and to write, handful as Python
- (-) Some frameworks are missing, but it's not the Go philosophy
- (-) Err management can be boring

My recommendation: Use go!

Comment: Nice answer @guillaumeblaquiere!